# why am I getting a 'no route matches' error in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-3-upgrade

I have in my haml:

```
= link_to("Calls Today", todo_path)
```

And in my routes.rb:

```ruby
match "todo/today" => "todo#show_date"
match "todo/today/campaign/:id" => "todo#show_date", :as => "todo"
```

My understanding is that 'todo_path' should find todo controller and show_date.

Comment: Please post relevant portions of the `rake routes` output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This route :

```
match "todo/today/campaign/:id" => "todo#show_date", :as => "todo"
```

Expects an id parameter. Therefore, your link_to should be like :

```
= link_to("Calls Today", todo_path(:id => your_id))
```